# Regression layer in convolutional neural network

Tags: neural-networks, python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

I am trying to do regression with a deep convolutional network. I am using the code from http://deeplearning.net/tutorial/lenet.html

Currently, the network is using logistic regression as its last layer which I want to remove. If I simply remove the layer

```
layer3 = LogisticRegression(input=layer2.output, n_in=500, n_out=10)
```

from the network, I will need to specify a cost instead of:

```
cost = layer3.negative_log_likelihood(y)
```

How can I specify an appropriate cost for doing regression? Each of my outputs should be 0 to 1, but not necessarily sum to 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open the source file of *LogisticRegression*, you will see the loss function being defined:

```
loss = -T.mean(T.log(self.p_y_given_x)[T.arange(y.shape[0]), y])
```

which minimizes the negative log-likelihood (but he uses the mean instead of the sum). In order to change to L2 loss function, you would need to write something like:

```
loss = T.sum(param ** 2)
```

in which *param* would be the error in your regression.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should check [Dr. LeCun's work](http://yann.lecun.com/exdb/publis/pdf/lecun-01a.pdf), which discusses several loss functions. It uses RBF's units in the output, so I'm not sure it's exactly what you need. As for me it's quite hard to implement it with Theano, so I use softmax and it works good for my tasks.